# Measure of a subset of the set $[0,1].$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $k$ be a positive integer and let $S_{k}=\{x\in [0,1]|\text{a decimal expansion of $x$ has a prime at its $k$th place}\} .$ Then the Lebesgue measure of $S_{k}$ is

$A.$ $0.$

$B.$ $\frac{4}{10}.$

$C.$ $(\frac{4}{10})^{k}.$

$D.$ $1.$

I tried for $S_{1}$ as $$
S_1 = [0.2,0.3) \cup [0.3,0.4) \cup [0.5,0.6) \cup [0.7,0.8)
$$ so $m(S_{1})=\frac{4}{10}.$ But how to find $m(S_{2}),m(S_{3})\cdot\cdot\cdot?$. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing $S_2$ as a union of intervals?

Comment: It is not surprising that the $k$-th digit is uniformly distributed, so $S_k$ always has measure $\frac{4}{10}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: For any positive integer $k$, we can write:

$$S_k = \bigcup_{d_1 = 0}^{9}\cdots \bigcup_{d_{k-1} = 0}^{9}[0.d_1\ldots d_{k-1}2,0.d_1\ldots d_{k-1}3) \cup [0.d_1\ldots d_{k-1}3,0.d_1\ldots d_{k-1}4) \cup [0.d_1\ldots d_{k-1}5,0.d_1\ldots d_{k-1}6) \cup [0.d_1\ldots d_{k-1}7,0.d_1\ldots d_{k-1}8)$$

How many intervals are in this union? Are they disjoint? What is the measure of each interval?

Comment: It will be same as $\frac{4}{10}$?????